# Check place details in Google Places API Dashboard

Tags: php, curl, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places to add my web-app's places to their API.

I send my `POST` requests with `cURL` and PHP, but when I come back in my Project's dashboard, I can't see any trace of my request.
However, when I try a `GET` request with the `place_id` that's sent back to me after my POST request, I retrieve my place details, so I can tell that my place has been added. And that `GET` request actually appears in my dashboard's activity

How can I know that my place has indeed been properly added to Google Places API?

Just to be clear, my request is not denied: I got an 'OK' status and an 'APP' scope. But I'd like to know how much time that it takes for a place added like I do to be validated.

Comment: It seems that my added places' scope is still 'APP', which means that they have not been validated by the moderator process. How can I know what's wrong with my request and why they have not been validated?

Comment: Typically it takes some time. Depends on the backlog that has Google data team.

Comment: Well ok then. I'll keep you posted in the next weeks.